# After executing code inside @BeforeTest its giving null pointer exception for @Test

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception, testng

After executing the`@BeforeTest` its showing `java.lang.NullPointerException` for `@Test` part.

Error displayed:

```
    Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 34173
    Only local connections are allowed.
    Sep 08, 2017 10:40:43 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
    FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest Aftertest
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at SampleTesting.Test1.Aftertest(Test1.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:958)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:606)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

    FAILED: Test1
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at SampleTesting.Test1.Test1(Test1.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


    ===============================================
        Default test
        Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
        Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================


    ===============================================
    Default suite
    Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================
```

---

**Code Used**

```
package SampleTesting;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.*;

    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

    public class NameClassTest {

        WebDriver driver;
        ChromeOptions options;


      @Test
      public void Test1() {
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          WebElement tabAgreement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("***Value***"));
          tabAgreement.click();

          WebElement btnNew = driver.findElement(By.xpath("***Value***"));
          btnNew.click();

          Select lstRecordType = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id***Value***));
          lstRecordType.selectByVisibleText("MSA");

          WebElement btnContinue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("***Value***"));
          btnContinue.click();

          WebElement txtAgreementName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("***Value***"));
          txtAgreementName.clear();
          txtAgreementName.sendKeys("***Value***");

          Date date = new Date();
          System.out.println("Date is "+ date);


      }
      @BeforeTest
      public void BeforeTest() {
          options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
          String exepath = 

        "C:\\\\Users\\UserNAme\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
              System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",exepath);
              WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
              driver.manage().window().maximize();
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              driver.get("***URL***");
              WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
              WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
              WebElement btnLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("Login"));

              userName.sendKeys("****userName****");
              password.sendKeys("****password****");
              btnLogin.click();

          }

          @AfterTest
          public void Aftertest() {
              WebElement drpUserName = driver.findElement(By.id***Value***);
              drpUserName.click();

              WebElement lnkLogout = driver.findElement(By.xpath(***Value***));
              lnkLogout.click();

              driver.close();

          }

        }
```

**TestNG.xml file**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
            <suite name="Suite_SuiteName">
              <test name="Test_TestName">
                <classes>
                  <class name="SuiteName.ClassName"/>
                </classes>
              </test> <!-- Test_TestName -->
            </suite> <!-- Suite_SuiteName -->
```

Its executing the block under `@BeforeTest` successfully but when its coming to `@Test` part its giving an error message - `Null Pointer exception`. I am not sure what mistake I made here in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have mentioned `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` in `@BeforeMethod` annotated method. So your webdriver instance limited for that method only.

So if go in `@test` annotated method it will find driver not initialized so throw the `NullPointerException`

Just remove `WebDriver` from here

```
 @BeforeTest
  public void BeforeTest() 
  {
      options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
      String exepath = "C:\\\\Users\\UserNAme\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",exepath);
      driver = new ChromeDriver(options);  // remove "WebDriver" from this line
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("***URL***");
```

Let me know if still have issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `@BeforeTest` annotated method you have this line

`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

This causes your code to shadow out the class level data member and so when your `@Test` methods try accessing the driver, you hit a `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, please change `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` to `driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` in your `@BeforeTest` annotated method.

On a side note, I would recommend that you either use one of the following instead of using the `@BeforeTest` because `@BeforeTest` methods are called only once per `<test>` tag. So if you have two test classes which are relying on the `@BeforeTest` method, then you are again looking at `NullPointerException`

1. `@BeforeClass` - so that the webdriver is instantiated once per test class and is then shared by all the `@Test` methods in the class. The issue would be that you would need to resort to sequential execution only, because parallel execution can cause test methods to step on each other's shoes.
2. `@BeforeMethod` - so that the webdriver is instatiated once for every `@Test` method. This causes a browser to be spun off for every test method. The flip side of this would be that you would need to use `ThreadLocal` if you want run the methods in parallel. If sequential execution is fine, then you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: Thanks Krishnan for sharing those 2 ways for enhancing my script.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating object of WebDriver outside @BeforeTests
as mentioned below,

```
public class nameClassTest {
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

  @BeforeTest
      public void BeforeTest()
{

}
```

that will resolve your issue.